# Regarding memset() function in c?

Tags: c, memset

For this program, I'm getting some weird output?

```
    char str[]= "almost every programmer should know memset!";
    memset(str,'*',5);
    puts(str);
```

Desired output:
   *****almost every programmer should know memset!
What I observed:
   *****t alomost every programmer should know memset!

For multiples of 6 only its showing correct output.

Comment: Is your observed output exact?

Comment: You most definitely didn't observe the output being *\*\*\*\*\*t alomost every programmer should know memset!* You probably got *\*\*\*\*\*t every programmer should know memset!*

Answer (score 6):

The output you are seeing is right:

`memset()` will set `'*'` for first 5 bytes of your array `str`.The rest of the string is kept as it is.

Answer (score 4):

In most cases, array names decay into a pointer to the first element, which means that your `memset()` call will set 5 bytes to `'*'`, starting from the first element of `str`. In other words, it will overwrite the first 5 letters with `'*'`, and the output will be:

```
*****t every programmer should know memset!
```